# UIActivityIndicator disappears as soon as actionSheet closes

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet, uiactivityindicatorview

I am initiating UIActivityIndicator from UIActionSheet's clickButtonAtIndex function. Here is the code

```
+(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

NSLog(@"AS Button Clicked %d",buttonIndex);

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

indicator.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 56, 56);
[indicator startAnimating];
[[actionSheet superview] addSubview:indicator];

}
```

And the code to initiate UIActionSheet is given below

```
UIActionSheet * actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: nil
                                                          delegate: self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                            destructiveButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                                 otherButtonTitles: @"Button1",
                               @"Button2", nil];

[actionSheet showFromRect: rect inView: view animated: YES];
```

However, the moment a button is clicked, UIActivityIndicator disappears along with UIActionSheet.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2):

The action sheet's superview is either a new window or some other view that covers the screen. When you dismiss the action sheet, this other window or view is removed as well.

Since you are adding the activity indicator to this other view, the activity indicator goes away with the rest of the action sheet.

You need to add the activity indicator to something unrelated to the action sheet.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. Stack Overflow's user interface is stupid.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting it into action sheet's superview. You dont know which view is that because action sheet view hierarchy is private and the superview disappears with the action sheet.

Put the indicator into one of your views instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `[[actionSheet superview] addSubview:indicator];`

Please edit this as `[self.view addSubview:indicator];`

You were adding the activity indicator to the `UIActionSheet` which would obviously disappear as soon as the `UIActionSheet` disappears.

Using the edited code you will be adding it to the `View` itself. This will now make the **Activity Indicator** visible even after your `UIActionSheet` dismisses.